# show a list of buyers that has contacted a rent

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

A rent can be contacted by many user to buy. I want to show the list of all users that has contacted a specific rent. Should i create a UserAPIView and show over there or show list of users in RentDetail? Which one is the best design?

Here is my model and serializer

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)

class Contact(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rental = models.ForeignKey(Rental, related_name="rent")
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    buyer_choice = models.CharField(choices=BUYER_CHOICES, max_length=1, null=False, blank=False)


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email',)

class RentalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    galleries = GallerySerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        fields = ('__all__')

class UserAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        List all the users
        """
        reply = {}
        try:
            users = User.objects.all()
            reply['data'] = UserSerializer(users, many=True).data
        except:
            reply['data'] = []
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)


class RentAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        """
         Returns a list of rents (or just rent if token is given)
        """
        reply = {}
        try:
            rents = Rental.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            buyer_id = self.request.query_params.get('buyer_id', None)
            if buyer_id:
                print ('buyer_id', buyer_id)
                rents = rents.filter(rent__buyer__id=buyer_id)
            if token:
                rent = rents.get(id=token)
                reply['data'] = RentalSerializer(rent).data
            else:
                reply['data'] = RentalSerializer(rents, many=True).data
        except Rental.DoesNotExist:
            return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
        except:
            return error.UnknownError().as_response()
        else:
            return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: This is a question about design preferences and isn't really something that StackOverflow can answer.

Comment: I thought i will get the guide as i have tried by myself too. Sorry if i posted the wrong question.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misunderstood. Is your question about API architecture or about UI layout?

Comment: Either way it's a matter of personal choice, however regarding API architecture, there are pros and cons both for having a highly normalised API structure vs. a big nested tree. You'll find a lot of discussion around that topic if you search for it.

Comment: I was talking about API architecture. Due to the two model Rental and Contact, i got confused on where should i show the data. Which serializer should i work on? I could do it but I am not confident enough to tell this is the right way or not.